# Racket Scheme - member? function conundrum

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

I am trying to use a member? function to determine the presence of a particular string of words in a user's input.

The member? function is use is:

```
    (define (member? item seq)
  (sequence-ormap (lambda (x)
                    (equal? item x))
                  seq))
```

However, the structure of my program requires me to do the following comparison:

(member? '(the names) '(the names of the basemen))

An example of its output is below:

```
> (car (car *strong-cues*))
'((the names) (their names))
> (car (car (car *strong-cues*)))
'(the names)
> (member? (car (car (car *strong-cues*))) '(the names of the basemen))
#f
```

"the names" is clearly in the user's input (which in this case is "the names of the basemen") However, the issue I see is that THIS is what is taking place:

Is (the names) in 'the or 'names or 'of or 'the or 'basemen?

Is there a way to do this comparison properly, so that searching for "the names" would return true if "the names" was a string inside of the user's input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't really `member` at all since you are searching for a sublist in a list. because of that you cannot use `ormap` since each iteration would only have one element while you expect to compare several. I suggest you make `prefix?`:

```
(define (prefix? what lst)
  ; implementation left as exercise
  <???>)

(prefix? '(b c) '(a b c d)) ; ==> #f
(prefix? '(b c) '(b c d))   ; ==> #t
```

This is fairly simple recursive thing where you compare element to element until the search list is empty. If either each element test is false or the haystack is empty it's false. Then you can easily make `find-sublist` with it:

```
(define (find-sublist sub lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) #f)
        ((prefix? sub lst) lst)
        (else (find-sublist sub (cdr lst))))))

(find-sublist '(c d) '(a b c d e f)) ; ==> (c d e f)
```

Here I return the list that has the prefix, like member does, but that can easily be changed to whatever you would want it to do.. index, `#t`, etc.

Comment: Your explanation is brief and informative. Thank you very much!!